# Creating C# DLL, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, soap

**A little background**:  I'm writing a set of C# classes to wrap a SOAP connector to another system called [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview).  The SOAP connector which Jira exposes has too many functions for my purposes, so I'm attempting to simplify the interface.

**My setup**: In C#/Visual Studio 2010, my solution is laid out as follows:

```
JiraService
    Properties/
        AssemblyInfo.cs
        Settings.settings/
    References/
        ...
        System.Web.Services
    Web References
        devjira.soap /* my connector to the jira soap reference i'm wrapping */
    Types/  /* these are data classes i'm trying to expose for the user */
        Comment.cs
        Issue.cs
        Project.cs
        User.cs
    app.config
    Jira.cs /* main class I'm trying to provide to user */
```

Jira.cs is in the `JiraService` namespace.  Comment.cs, Issue.cs, Project.cs, and User.cs are all in the `JiraService.Types` namespace.  Jira.cs essentially exposes a few methods which either take or return the classes found in the `Types` directory.  Under the properties I have the Default namespace set to JiraService and the Output type set to Class Library.

**My Problem**:  When I build the solution I get out `JiraService.dll`.  When I add this reference to another project, the Jira, Comment, Issue, Project, and User classes are not in the JiraService or JiraService.Types namespaces of the included .dll.  The only available namespace is `JiraService.devjira.soap`, which is the library I'm trying to simplify and hide!  What am I doing wrong?  Why are my classes not showing up in the final library?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Have you checked that access modifiers of classes are "public"?

Comment: That was my problem.  I didn't realize that they needed to explicitly be marked as public.  Coming from scripting languages and C, that didn't stick out immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to see code to tell for sure, but a few things to check;
1. Did you name your namespaces correctly in all the classes? Folder structure doesn't matter, its the namespace attribute that counts.
2. Are your classes public?

Beyond that, post some sample code please..

Comment: Thank you sir!  It was the classes not being explicitly marked as public.  You saved me quite a bit of frustration =)